# Show that $\int_0^1 {\sin \left( {\pi x} \right)} x^x \left( {1 - x} \right)^{1 - x} \mathrm dx = \frac{{\pi e}}{{24}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

While going through a [list](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1674162p10659982) (Problem $17$) of interesting integrals I have come across this one

> $$\int_0^1 {\sin \left( {\pi x} \right)} x^x \left( {1 - x} \right)^{1 - x} \mathrm dx = \frac{{\pi e}}{{24}}$$

I have tried integration by parts with $u=x^x \left( {1 - x} \right)^{1 - x}$ and $\mathrm dv=\sin \left( {\pi x} \right)$ but this ended up in and even more complicated integral. To use the series representation of $e^{x\ln(x)}$ and respectively $e^{(1-x)\ln(1-x)}$ does not appeared to be helpful at all even after reshaping it all in the form $(1-x)\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^x$. Then I thought about using Euler's Reflection Formula to get rid of the $\sin(\pi x)$ and work in terms of the Gamma Function instead. Hence this formula only holds for $x\notin\mathbb{Z}$ $-$ and the limits are given by $0$ and $1$ $-$ I guess this is not possible here. My last try was to use the Weierstrass Expansion of the sine function but I guess this is not the right approach either.

> Could someone please provide a whole solution since I have no further idea how to deal with this integral? I have searched here on MSE but it does not seem like someone hast asked something like this before. Nevertheless tell me when I have overseen something or when you can link a former question which is helpful for understanding the process of evaluating this definite integral.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Nosrati Ah, okay. Thank you. I did not found this.

Comment: Sorry about it!

Comment: An extension is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1884617/108128

Comment: @Nosrati Thank you again. I will look through these two answers to understand the integral completely :)