# alternating sum of zeta functions minus one is one half

Tags: riemann-zeta, alternative-proof

During my work on a different infinite series I happened to prove that

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k (\zeta(k)-1)=\frac{1}{2}$
 where
 $ \displaystyle\zeta(k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k}$

My question is whether this relation was known before and is of any interest to others.

Comment: Yes. And it can be proven by writing $\zeta(k)-1$ as an infinite series, and then switching the order of the two summations. Also, the value of its non-alternating version is $1$.

Comment: That's true. Thanks.

Comment: Which also means that sum of even zeta-1 functions is 3/4 and sum of odd zeta-1 functions is 1/4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Usually, the following were a comment, but since you're asking whether they are of interest... I'll make it an "answer". It is from an answer of mine to a thread "surprising identities" [earlier in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505367/surprising-identities-equations/505806#505806))*

Some zeta-identies have been much surprising to me.

Let's denote the value $\zeta(s)-1$ as $\zeta_1(s)$ then
$$ \small \begin{array} {}
1 \zeta_1(2) &+&1 \zeta_1(3)&+&1 \zeta_1(4)&+&1 \zeta_1(5)&+&  ... &=&1\\
1 \zeta_1(2) &+&2 \zeta_1(3)&+&3 \zeta_1(4)&+&4 \zeta_1(5)&+&  ... &=&\zeta(2)\\
             & &1 \zeta_1(3)&+&3 \zeta_1(4)&+&6 \zeta_1(5)&+&  ... &=&\zeta(3)\\ 
             & &            & &1 \zeta_1(4)&+&4 \zeta_1(5)&+&  ... &=&\zeta(4)\\ 
             & &            & &            & &1 \zeta_1(5)&+&  ... &=&\zeta(5)\\ 
 ...         & & & & & & & &... &= &  ...
\end{array}
$$
There are very similar stunning alternating-series relations:

$$ \small \begin{array} {}
1 \zeta_1(2) &-&1 \zeta_1(3)&+&1 \zeta_1(4)&-&1 \zeta_1(5)&+&  ... &=&1/2\\
             & &2 \zeta_1(3)&-&3 \zeta_1(4)&+&4 \zeta_1(5)&-&  ... &=&1/4\\
             & &            & &3 \zeta_1(4)&-&6 \zeta_1(5)&+&  ... &=&1/8\\ 
             & &            & &            & &4 \zeta_1(5)&-&  ... &=&1/16\\ 
 ...         & & & & & & & &... &= &  ...
\end{array}
$$

*(An even older, likely difficult to read but more involved, discussion of identities like this and how one can arrive at them can be found in [this pdf](https://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/10_4_zetasums.pdf) )*

Comment: These are truly amazing, thanks for sharing them and thanks for the pdf.