# How can I prove the convergence of a power-tower?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

[In here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505367/surprising-identities-equations) I saw that $$x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{.{^{.^{.}}}}}}}}}}$$ exists as a real number (convergent) if and only if $$x\in[e^{-e}, e^\frac{1}{e}].$$ How can I prove this??

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration. What you are asked has been established by Euler.

Comment: **Hint:** $y=x^y$.

Comment: You should define this infinite power tower as $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$ where $$a_0 = 1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad a_n=x^{a_{n-1}}$$ This lets you formulate the question precisely, unambiguously (otherwise it's not clear what exactly an infinite power tower *is*).

Comment: @Lucian *Assuming convergence* of $y$, we can say $$y=x^y$$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: Correct. $($I was referring to how one might determine the limits of the interval of convergence$)$.

Comment: These may be equivalent, but it is far from clear that one is the same question as the other, and the answers do not seem to match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [Knuth's up-arrow notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation#Definition),

$$\newcommand{\W}{\operatorname{W}}x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{.{^{.^{.}}}}}}}}}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} x\uparrow\uparrow n$$

Let $\displaystyle y = \lim_{n \to \infty} x\uparrow\uparrow n$ and let us assume that it *does* converge.

Then, $\displaystyle x^y = \lim_{n \to \infty} x \uparrow\uparrow(n+1)$

As $n \to \infty$, $n + 1 \to \infty$ (Roughly speaking $\infty \pm n \to \infty$)

Hence, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x\uparrow\uparrow n \equiv \lim_{n \to \infty} x \uparrow\uparrow(n+1) \implies \boxed{\displaystyle y = x^y}$

A trivial solution here is $(x,y) = (1,1)$

The variables $x$ and $y$ in $y = x^y$ are not separable (we cannot isolate the any of the variables here on to any one side ) in this equation by usual algebraic manipulations.

However, we can use the [Lambert $\W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to isolate the variables,
$$y = - \frac{\W(-\ln x)}{\ln x}$$

Considering the real values of $\W$ and Using the [fixed point iteration method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration),
 it can be seen that $\displaystyle x\in\left[\frac1{e^{e}}, e^\frac{1}{e}\right]$

Good Luck :)

Comment: For anyone like me not seeing how to get to $y = - \frac{W(-\ln x)}{\ln x}$. The $W$ function satisfies $W(z) = w$ if and only if $z = we^w$, so we want to get to something of this form. Start with $y = x^y$, divide by $x^y$ to get $yx^{-y} = 1$, and rewrite as $ye^{-y\ln x } = 1$. Now multiply by $-\ln x$ to match the exponent: $-y\ln x\ e^{-y\ln x} = -\ln x$. This is in the desired form, and we get $-y \ln x = W(-\ln x)$, ergo $y = \frac{W(-\ln x)}{-\ln x}$.

Answer (score 7):

The equation

$$x^{x^{x\cdots}}$$

is not well defined, we have to find some way to define it to find its value.

There are two sensible definitions:

The first is to say that the thing in the exponent is actually the same as the entire thing, which is written as

$$y=x^y$$

And solving for $y$ here would give the solution.

To solve this we need a special multivalued function called the [Lambert $\newcommand{\W}{\operatorname{W}}\W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which satisfies $z=\W(z)\cdot\exp(\W(z))$ for all complex $z$. The solution is then

$$y=-\frac{\W(-\log x)}{\log x}$$

If we restrict attention to real-valued $\W$, the function is defined only for $x \ge −1/e$, and is double-valued on $(−1/e, 0)$.

Since the argument is $-\log x$, which is a decreasing, and $-\log(e^{1/e})=-\frac1e$, our solution is only defined when $x\le e^{1/e}$ and when the logarithm is defined. Therefore, under this definition, the function is defined (not necessarily uniquely) and real when $x\in[0,e^{1/e}]$

---

There is however another definition:

Define the sequence $a_n$

$$a_0=x\qquad\qquad a_n=x^{a_{n-1}}$$

And the value were looking for is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$$

Which can be written as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x\uparrow\uparrow n$$

In [Nicks answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1089541/132791), it is explained why this is the same as the definition $y=x^y$

Comment: Actually, it can also be informally expressed as $^n x$.

Comment: @Nick sure, thats just another way to write the same thing

Answer (score 1):

As **Lucian** mentioned above, I have considered the function $$f(y)=y^{\frac{1}{y}}$$ $$\lim_{y\to 0^+}f(y)=0$$   $$\lim_{y\to \infty}f(y)=1$$  Also $$f'(y)=y^{\frac{1}{y}}\Big(\dfrac{1}{y^2}-\dfrac{\ln y}{y^2}\Big).$$ Using this, we have maximum of $f(y)$ occurs at $y=e.$ Hence $$f(y)\le e^{\frac{1}{e}},\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall y\ge 0.$$ But I did not have an idea about obtaining the lower bound $e^{-e}.$