# How do I find the value of this weird expression?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, infinite-product

How can I find the value of the expression  $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^...}} $?  I wrote a computer program to calculate the value, and the result comes out to be 2 (more precisely 1.999997). Can anyone explain what's happening? Is there any general method to calculate these expressions? I am new to these problems.Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
On looking at the answer by Clement C., I thought I could generalize the method to find the value of any expression of the form $\sqrt[n]{n}^{\sqrt[n]{n}^{\sqrt[n]{n}^...}} $. The value should be $n$, but this is not the case. This is the graph for $n<50$.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\sqrt2^x=x$  ...

Comment: This is called [infinite tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) denoted by $^\infty a=\underbrace{a^{a^{a^{\ldots}}}}_{n\textrm{ times}}$

Comment: An important fact: $x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}$ can never exceed $e$, which it achieves for $x=e^{1/e}$.  In particular, the value for $x=3^{1/3}$ cannot be $3$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089458/how-can-i-prove-the-convergence-of-a-power-tower

Comment: For your more general method the limit should be 1. Just consider $\lim_{n \to \infty}\ n^{n^{-1}}$.

Comment: If we let $S$ be the solution to the sum, then for a given $n$ we know that $S$ satisfies $\frac{\log(S)}{S} = \frac{\log(n)}{n}$. One solution to this is $n$ but notice this is not the only solution. For example $n=4$, both 2 and 4 satisfy the equation and the value you are seeing the convergence to in your graph is the solution $\leq e$.

Comment: Note that if we have one solution $n$, the other can be found by equating $\frac{\log(n)}{n} = \frac{\log(n^k)}{n^k} = \frac{\log(n)}{(1/k) n^k}$ and solving $\frac{1}{k} = n^{1-k}$ for $k$. You can easily verify this for the 2,4 solution case.

Answer (score 20):

We don't allow infinite expressions, so first you need to define what it means.  One way to make sense of it is as a sequence, $a_1=\sqrt 2, a_2 =\sqrt 2 ^{\sqrt 2}, a_3=\sqrt 2 ^{\sqrt 2^{\sqrt 2}},a_n=\sqrt 2^{a_{n-1}}$ and ask if the sequence has a limit as $n \to \infty$  If the limit exists, call it $L$. Then $L=\sqrt 2^L$, which is satisfied by $2$.  To prove the limit exists, show that $a_n \lt 2 \implies a_{n+1} \lt 2$ and $a_n \gt 1 \implies a_{n+1} \gt a_n$.  The sequence is now monotone and bounded above, so has a limit.

Comment: All this is also true for $L=4$: $4=\sqrt{2}^4$,
$a_n \lt 4 \implies a_{n+1} \lt 4$.
How would you rule $L=4$ out?

Comment: @g.kov The only two real candidates for $L$ from the equation $L=\sqrt{2}^L$ are $2$, and as you noted, $4$. The sequence $a_n$ is bounded above by $2$, so $4$ cannot be the limit since $4>2$. Thus, the only remaining candidate for the limit is $2$.

Comment: @Peter Olson: Perhaps, the answer of Clement C. is more complete,
it depends on the initial value $a_1$. 
Why would we set $a_1=\sqrt{2}$?
If we set $a_1=4$ then we get a constant sequence $a_n=4$.

Comment: @g.kov:  we set $a_1=\sqrt 2$ because that is the term with one $\sqrt 2$ in it and I was making the sequence so that term $a_n$ has $n\ \sqrt 2$'s

Comment: @g.kov Sure, $4$ is the limit of the sequence $a_n=4$, I'm sure everybody agrees with that, but it's not the limit of the sequence he defines in the answer with $a_1=\sqrt{2}$ and $a_n=\sqrt{2}^{a_{n-1}}$. I was talking about how to rule out the possibility $L=4$ from *this* sequence, not from some other sequence not mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Ross Millikan: There is no spacial in the value $\sqrt{2}$, we can start with e.g. $1$ or $2$, or $\mathrm{e}$, or $\pi$ with the same result $x=2$,
or we can start it with $4$ and get $x=4$. 
The whole tower $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^...}}$ object 
is not an expression that starts from $\sqrt{2}$ and unfolds infinitely down,
as it may look.
The equation $x=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^...}}$
just has two real solutions as stated in the answer of Clement C.,
much like the equation $x^2=1$ has two real solutions $x=\pm1$.
There is no reason to discriminate a second real solution here.

Comment: I think the approach is good, but the confusion might be arising from not showing that 2 is the least upper bound. This way we also don't need to assume $L$ exists.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId:  The point is I don't have to show that 2 is a least upper bound.  I have shown that it is an upper bound and that the sequence is monotonic, which proves there is a limit.  I have excluded 4 as a limit because 2 is an upper bound.  I have not shown that there is not another potential limit (which must be less than 2).  That can be done, but I haven't done it.  The idea of "starting with 4" is nonsense-I have defined a sequence and it starts with $\sqrt 2$.  If someone wants to define another way of approaching this question, they are free to do so.

Answer (score 6):

As WillO wrote, once properly defined as the limit of the recursive sequence $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2}^{a_n}$ (which exists by monotonicity, for any initial value $a_0$), the value $x$ you are looking for satisfies the equation
$$
\sqrt{2}^x =x
$$
(can you see why?), or equivalently
$$
\frac{\ln 2}{2} = \frac{\ln x}{x}
$$
(by taking the logarithm and rearranging the terms). Clearly, $2$ is a solution *(to this equation, that any solution $x$ to the original problem must in particular satisfy)*, as is $4$: to show that these are the only ones, observe that $x\mapsto \frac{\log x}{x}$ is increasing on $(0,1]$, and decreasing on $[1,\infty)$. Now, depending on the initial value $a_0$ of your sequence, the solution has to be one of the two. I assume you want $a_0=1$.

Comment: I only stated that 4 *could* be a limit of the recursive sequence, from solving the equation (not that it was). Any solution must be in $\{2,4\}$.

Comment: You post says "Clearly, 2 is a solution, as is 4". To me that sounds that you claim it to be a valid solution. You may want to consider an edit.

Comment: @mjnichol: is it clearer now? (I added a sentence to make the distinction explicit).

Comment: @Prasun Biswas: $\large e^{e^{-1}}\approx 1.444667861\lt 2$. 
Are you suggesting that $x=2$ cannot be a solution?

Comment: @g.kov, sorry, I made a small error in my comment. Editing it now!

Comment: Damn, I can't edit it. Anyway, what I meant is that the infinite tetration $y=^\infty a$ can take values of $x$ only upto $x=e$ corresponding to the unique solution $y=e^{e^{-1}}$ at $x=e$. @g.kov

Comment: +1 for dependence on the initial value. 
Perhaps the common misunderstanding is that 
since we see a lot of $\sqrt{2}$ we assume that
this tower "starts" somewhere high at $a_1=\sqrt{2}$
and infinitely unfolds from there down.
But this is not exactly true, it "starts" at any height 
with the limit value already,
which equally can be 2 as well as 4.

Comment: @Prasun Biswas: That what I thought it is.
Then your comment is not relevant. Btw, you can delete it

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite your expression as $$\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{...}}=2^{(\frac{1}{2})^{2^{...}}}$$
Clearly multiplying the powers out you end up with $$2^{1^{1^{...}}}=2$$

Comment: I don't quite follow your "clearly multiplying the powers out".

Comment: @rwolst I think he means a^b^c = a^(bc)

Comment: I think this the best solution and also the best explanation.  Tbh, I didn't really understand the other answers.

Comment: I don't think this is logically correct i.e. the second line doesn't immediately follow from the first and the fact that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$. (Instead see Clement's answer). For example if $f(k)$ represents $k$, $\sqrt{2}$'s in the expression can you use this method for $f(3)$ say?

Comment: I agree the other two answers are clearer and this would not be a sufficient proof for a textbook, but it shows some intuition. You can't use the method for $f(3)$, but the question doesn't need you to - the expression has infinitely many terms. The question whether the total number of them is even or odd is not well defined, and you can clearly rewrite each consecutive two of them as $x^{(\frac{1}{2})^2}$ or, if you prefer, $x^{2^\frac{1}{2}}$, leaving you with an expression made of repeated $x^{1^1}$.

Comment: This is saying a^b^c = (a^b)^c = a^(bc), but I think the question is about a^(b^c).

Comment: @adrug I was using $f(3)$ as an example to illustrate what is going wrong with your method and not to highlight any even or odd issue. Essentially, the terms aren't cancelling as clearly as you say they should be.