# Solving $a^{a^{a^{\cdots\infty}}}=2$?

Tags: exponentiation

I was thinking about the problem $a^{a^{a^{\cdots}}}=2$, I thought of taking $x = a^{a^{a^\cdots}}$, then we get $a^x = x$ but we know as per the question that $x=2$ so we have to solve for $a^x=x$ or $a^2=2$ which we get $a=\sqrt{2}$, but this is also true for $x=4$ for which $a=\sqrt{2}$ also, which seems kind of incorrect?

Comment: How is true for $4$?

Comment: As we get $a^4=4$

Comment: @ZacharySelk I see that it contradicts the method but why ?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089458/how-can-i-prove-the-convergence-of-a-power-tower

Comment: The difference is $x = 2$ is an attractive fixed point for the iteration $x \mapsto \sqrt{2}^x$ while $x = 4$ isn't. If you start from any $x \in [0,4)$, the iterated sequence will converges to $2$. if you start from $x \in (4,\infty)$, the sequence diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmP3sFIZ0XE&t=295s