# Is it possible to express $\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}^{\cdots}}\right) dx$ in elementary functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, power-towers

let $\epsilon >0$, I tried to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}^{\cdots}}\right) dx$ , using the fact $x= \cos t$  yield to have integrand using $\sin $  function seems is not easy to get such closed form by this variable change , For one iteration by means $\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right) dx$ we have the integrand [converge approximately](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28%28+sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29%5E%28%28sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29%29%29+%2C+x%3D0+to+1) to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}$,  Now for some odd iterations we have $l=0.89..$ and for even iterations we have $l=0.9..$ , Now if we fixe $\epsilon$ at   at some small value such that $x$ [lie at a least between](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28-e%29%3Csqrt%281-x%5E2%29%3Ce%5E%281%2Fe%29) $(0,0.99782)$ to get convergence according to below comment by @Oscar Lanzi and @Sangchul Lee , Now my question here is : Is it possible to express the titled integral in elementary functions ?

**Edit:** I edited the question according to the two below montioned comments to assure convergence also my Goal was to express the titled integrand tower in elementary functions

Comment: No.  The integrand itself does not converge over the entire range of integration.

Comment: Check [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1089458/9340) and/or [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.05559.pdf), for instance, for the convergence of infinite power tower.

Comment: It is $\int_0^1\frac{x(x+1)e^x}{\sqrt{e^{2xe^x}-1}}\,dx$, highly unlikely to have a closed form.

Comment: The copy of this question is alread posted [here in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/365692/51189)

Comment: If the question is about the integral
$$I = \int_0^{\sqrt {1 - e^{-2 e}}}
 \sqrt {1 - x^2} \! \uparrow \uparrow \! \infty \, dx,$$
then, since $\int f^{-1}(x) \, dx = \int y \, df(y)$,
$$I = \int_{1/e}^1 \frac {y^{2/y - 1} (1 - \ln y)} {\sqrt {1 - y^{2/y}}} dy \approx
.836333 \hspace{1.5px} .$$

Answer (score 1):

If we let

$$y=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{1-x^2}\uparrow\uparrow n)$$

then we have

$$y=(\sqrt{1-x^2})^y\implies x=\sqrt{1-y^{2/y}}$$

and the integral can be represented more neatly as

$$I=\exp(-e)\sqrt{1-\exp(-2\exp(1-e))}+\int_{\exp(-e)}^1\sqrt{1-y^{2/y}}~\mathrm dy$$

where $I$ is the original integral over the largest subinterval of $[0,1]$ where it converges.

Although it is highly unlikely a closed form exists, this form is easy to numerically compute and gives

$$I\simeq0.807316213493$$

The same approach, however, is not so nice if one attempts to find the limits of the even and odd heights over the entire interval $[0,1]$, since one needs to solve for $x$ from

$$y=\sqrt{1-x^2}~\widehat~~(\sqrt{1-x^2}~\widehat~~y)$$

and this will require multiple branches of the Lambert W function.

Comment: I don't know why this question is not well received [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/365692/51189)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a "research question" I suppose.