# Limit of a sequence involving power of the previous term.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given a positive real number $x$, a sequence $\{a_n(x)\}$ is defined as follows:
$$a_1(x)=x\ \ \text{and}\ \ a_n(x)=x^{a_{n-1}(x)}\ \ \ \text{recursively for all}\  n\geq 2.$$Determine the largest value of $x$ for which $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n(x)$ exists.

I observe that at $x=1$, sequence converges, whereas at $x=2$ sequence diverges. So $1\leq x<2$.

But I am unable to  find the largest value. Is it somehow related with derivative? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This sequence is basically an infinite potency tower. If you look at the first few iterations you get
$$
a_1(x)=x, a_2(x)=x^x, a_3(x) = x^{x^x}, ..., a_n(x) = x\uparrow \uparrow n
$$
also known as Knuth's up arrow notation.

This post [How can I prove the convergence of a power-tower?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089458/how-can-i-prove-the-convergence-of-a-power-tower) is probably what you are looking for. The maximum value is $e^\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: If you find an identical question with answers then you can flag the question as a duplicate instead of posting an answer which is essentially a link to another answer.

Comment: Ah I didn't know about the flagging thing. Thanks for that info! But as what should I flag this question? Probably "in need of moderator intervention", right?

Comment: You can flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't see that option. I only see "spam", "rude or abusive" or "in need of moderator intervention" as flagging options

Comment: Perhaps because it is closed already. Otherwise there should be a "Flag -> a duplicate” option where you can enter the duplicate target. – With more reputation (>= 3K) the procedure changes: Then you can “vote to close” a question.

Comment: Ok thanks for the detailed explanation!