# Find the maximum value of $x$ for which $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n(x)$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Given a positive real number $x,$ a sequence $\{a_n(x)\}_{n \geq 1}$ is defined as follows $:$
>
> $$a_1(x) = x\ \ \text {and}\ \ a_n (x) = x^{a_{n-1} (x)}\ \text {recursively for all}\ n \geq 2.$$
>
> Determine the largest value of $x$ for which $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n (x)$ exists.

How to tackle this problem? A small hint will be warmly appreciated.

Thanks a bunch.

$\textbf {Source} :$ NBHM PhD Screening Test $2021.$

Comment: This might be helpful... https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/J09727._Marshall_Ash.pdf

Comment: Read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089458/how-can-i-prove-the-convergence-of-a-power-tower/1089541#1089541)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a problem regarding an infinite tower of exponentials. Maybe checking this page and it's references you may approach something. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html.

PS: I can not comment because haven't reached 50 rep. Thats why I post this as an answer and not just a comment.

Comment: I have found in the link that the infinite tower converges if and only if $e^{-e} \leq x \leq e^{\frac {1} {e}}.$ But it isn't proved there. Do you know any proof of this fact? If so, could you please share some idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really, sorry. If i find something I'll let you know.

Comment: I think I got it. At least the upper bound.

Comment: If the limit exists and equals to $y$ say then we have a functional equation $x^y = y$ or in other words $x = y^{\frac {1} {y}}.$ We need to maximize $x$ and hence we just need to compute the global maxima of the function $y \mapsto y^{\frac {1} {y}}.$ Isn't it so? Now if you compute the maxima it will be attained exactly at the point $y = e.$ Hence the largest possible value of $x$ for which the given limit exists turns out to be $e^{\frac {1} {e}}.$

Comment: Sounds good. And it matches the result mentioned before. In this case it should be enough for your answer because you're looking for the largest value of $x$.

Comment: Yes @FelipeCruzV10. BTW Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @RabinKumarChakraborty. I have a simple answer but for some completely unapparent reason your question has been closed. (?)

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10. Why has this question been closed ?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: I don't know. Some people in this website thought that they are the smartest persons in the globe. But actually they are bloody idiots.