# Are there any (more) consecutive numbers that are functional in the Pythagorean Theorem?

Tags: trigonometry, real-numbers, pythagorean-triples

The numbers three, four, and five can be implanted in the Pythagorean process (3=a, 4=b, 5=c) to equal a correct right triangle. But my question is, are there any more directly consecutive numbers that can be used in the Pythagorean Theorem to equal a functional right triangle?

Comment: Direct consecutive numbers as in $3,4,5$ or $23,24,25$, the answer is no. $3,4,5$ is the only consecutive triplet that satisfies the pythagorean theorem $a^2+b^2=c^2$

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
a^2+(a+1)^2=(a+2)^2
\end{eqnarray*}
Now do the algebra.

Comment: As a side note, when the Pythagorean theorem is "extended", then you can go nuts like I did here :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505367/surprising-identities-equations/505421#505421