# About $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left( x\right )}{x} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^ 2\left( x\right )}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

How to show $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left( x\right )}{x} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^ 2\left( x\right )}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x$ ?

I've found this identity in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506787/). Following the comment by rnorris in that post "use integration by parts, starting from the right-hand side. Let $u=\sin^2(x)$, and $dv=x^{-2}dx$. Look at trig identities that involve the product $\sin(x)\cos(x)$."

I arrived to $$-\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\Big\vert_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(2x)}{x}\mathrm dx$$ where I used the trig identity $\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(x)+\cos(x)\sin(x)$ to change  $\sin(x)\cos(x)$.

Could someone tell me what can be done next?

I don't see how I could  modify the integral to have $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left( x\right )}{x} \mathrm{d}x $

Also, the trig identity $\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(x)+\cos(x)\sin(x)$, was that the one to be applied in the first place?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot have $-\sin^2 x/x$ after integration by parts since the definite integral is not a function of $x$. You have to evaluate it at the endpoints.

Comment: @Gary right right, sorry.

Comment: So that part becomes $0$ and you are left with the integral of $\sin(2x)/x$. Now make the change of integration variables $t=2x$.

Comment: @Gary indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ax=t$
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ax}{x} dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt$$
$I$ is independent of $a$.

Comment: OP has already shown the second integral as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{sin 2x}{x} dx$

Comment: You are right, very sorry.

Comment: But isn't this term -$$-\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x}$$ still there ?

Comment: @user215805 no, I actually didn't write correctly (sorry), see my edit. And actually I should have write that using limits. And then that'd go to $0$.

Comment: @Veronika Rmz, Yes, that looks better now.

Comment: If $a\le 0$, this is FALSE.

Comment: Yes  you are right. I need to mention $a>0$.

Comment: For $a>0$, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ax}{x} dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ax}{ax} \mathrm dax$$

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the trig identity you should do a change of variable.

Let $u = 2x$.

Comment: The downvote doesnt make sense,it seems the downvoter overlooked OP's work+1

Answer (score 1):

Since this
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left( x\right )}{x} \mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2\left( x\right )}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x$$
is really beautiful, I'am not satisfied to be a bystander.
The left one is mostly known and we can evaluate the right one by Laplace techniques since both are even.
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin^2\left( x\right )\frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x&=2\int_0^{\infty}\mathcal{L}\left[\sin^2\left(t\right)\right](x)\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s^2}\right](x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2}{4x + x^3}x\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2}{2^2+ x^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\pi.
\end{align}